# Not able to run command via wsl.exe

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run this commands from a python script:

```
def raw(path_avd_py, path_avd, snp_name, out_file):
    if OS == 'Windows':
        cmd_raw = f"wsl.exe -e sh -c 'python3 {path_avd_py} -a {path_avd} 
        -s {snp_name} -o {out_file}'"
    else:
        cmd_raw = f'python3 {path_avd_py} -a {path_avd} -s {snp_name} -o {out_file}'
    subprocess.Popen(cmd_raw, shell=True)
    time.sleep(25)
    return None


def idiffer(i_path, raw_1, raw_2, path, state):
    if OS == 'Windows':
        cmd_idiff = f"wsl.exe -e sh -c 'python3 {i_path} {raw_1} {raw_2}'"
    [...]
    file = os.path.join(path, f'{state}.idiff')
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        subprocess.Popen(cmd_idiff, stdout=f, text=True)
```

If im executing cmd_raw with subprocess.run from a python-shell (Powershell), things are working. If im try running this via script, this exception occurs, using different shells:

-e sh: avdecrypt-master\avdecrypt.py: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

-e bash: avdecrypt-master\avdecrypt.py: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
avdecrypt-master\avdecrypt.py: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I already tried os.system, os.run([list]) no change.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not clear why you are invoking `sh` or `bash` here, or `wsl` for that matter. Running Python as a subprocess of itself is also frequently something you should avoid; instead, `import` the code you want to run, and simply call the relevant function directly.

Comment: I'm not able to compile some dependencies in windows, which are necessary to run this script. To compile those under unix-flavoured systems are no problem. So i have to call some function from wsl. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Still you should not need `sh` to run Python, or Python as a subprocess of itself.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a similar question, I found a solution, which is working for me:
Apparently calling scripts with some argv has to be in one single quotation mark and can be executed via run (in my case important, because the process has to be terminated). This leads to a form like:

```
cmd = ['wsl.exe', '-e', 'bash', '-c', '-a foo -b bar [...]']
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

Lib shlex is helping here and formatting the strings like subprocess is needing it:

```
cmd_finished = shlex.split(cmd)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html